# Segmentfault trying to access value in struct from a function

Tags: c++, function, linked-list, segmentation-fault, nodes

```
void remove( const int & info, AvlNode * & node ) {
  //current holdes leftmost/rightmost leaf
  AvlNode*current = node;
  AvlNode*temp = node;

  if(current->element == info){
    //deleted node is in root
    AvlNode*rootreplace = current;
    rootreplace = current->right;
    while(rootreplace->left != NULL){
      rootreplace = rootreplace->left;
    }

    int c2=rootreplace->element;
    cout << c2;
    remove(c2,node);
    removeleftmost(c2,node);

    cout << c2;
    //node->element = c2;
```

root and node are interchangeable for this
node is set to the root node which is the value I'm trying to change(element).
I can output the `root->element and rootrepalace->element` works fine
, however when i set

`node->element = rootreplace->element` I get a segment fault 11. Leading me to believe it has something to do with how I'm accessing these nodes tho I can't find much online.

Comment: Try to "cout" the pointers (not the objects pointed to) `node`, `current`, and `rootreplace`, just to see when and why some become null.

Answer (score 0):

error came from    `AvlNode*rootreplace = current;` changing to     `AvlNode*rootreplace = node;` fixed this.